# OAuth 2.0 ios swift implementation

Tags: ios, swift, github, ios8, oauth-2.0

I am not sure If I can ask questions of github related source code in stackoverflow but I am stuck trying to understand the code base.

Source :        https://github.com/gabriel-jones/OAuthSwift

I am trying to integrate OAuth2.0 into my project for various authentications.
On the read.md , it says

```
 let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********",
    authorizeUrl:   "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
    responseType:   "token"
)

oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "oauth-                    swift://oauth-callback/instagram"), scope: "likes+comments",   state:"INSTAGRAM", success: {credential, response in
println(credential.oauth_token) }, failure: failureHandler)
```

I fail to understand how success can be sent as a parameter ?

I tried something like :

```
    var credential =  OAuthSwiftCredential(consumer_key: "****", consumer_secret: "****")
    var response : NSHTTPURLResponse? = nil

    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(callbackURL: NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/"), scope: "***", state: "****", params: emptyDictionary, success: {
        credential, response
    }, failure: failureHandler())
```

I looked at the implementation classes but didn't seem to grasp how to call the authorizeWithCallbackURL() method. Please let me know.ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

do like this,

```
oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: encodedCallBackUrl!)!, scope: "your%20scope", state: state, success: {
        credential, response in
        // Success
        println(credential.oauth_token)


        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in

        // Failure 

            println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Please change your scope as your desired `scope: "your%20scope"` in the above code